# pandas select the minimum and max of each column and create a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, min

this is my dataframe:

```
A,B,C,D   
10,1,2,3
 1,4,7,3
10,5,2,3
40,7,9,3
9,9,5,0
```

I have just learned thank to you how to create a new dataframe selecting according to the min and max of a specific column. Thanks to @CHRD and @Quang Hoang.

I have just realize that this it not what I want. I would like to have a new dataframe with two  row where in each column of the new dataframe has the min and max of each column of my dataframe. This is the expected result:

```
     A,B,C,D   
min  1,1,2,0
max 40,9,9,3
```

I have tried with this command but it seems to not work.

```
dfr_new = dfr[dfr.columns].min())
```

Comment: Answer to the PS: no. You got answers to your previous question and they  answer the question you asked. Please accept one of the answer or upvote to "reward" the people that put effort to answer it. you will get new answer here and all is good :) Moreover some people might be looking for what you asked in the previous question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can just call `.agg` on your entire dataframe.

```
df.agg(['min','max'])
      A  B  C  D   
min   1  1  2  0
max  40  9  9  3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get that using this
`pd.DataFrame({'min': df.min(), 'max': df.max()}).T`

```
    A   B   C   D
min 1   1   2   0
max 40  9   9   3
```

This is the dataframe i used.

```
    A   B   C   D
0   10  1   2   3
1   1   4   7   3
2   10  5   2   3
3   40  7   9   3
4   9   9   5   0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.describe().loc[['min','max']].astype(int)

    A   B   C   D
min 1   1   2   0
max 40  9   9   3
```